# OpenCV - Creating a video from a set of images in a directory

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a video from a sequence of images. Below is my code.

```
import os
import cv2

mean_width = 6000
mean_height = 4000

def generate_video():
    image_folder = 'C:/New folder/Images/q/'
    video_name = 'myvideo.avi'
    os.chdir("C:/New folder/Images/q/")

    images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder)
              if img.endswith(".jpg") or
              img.endswith(".jpeg") or
              img.endswith("png")]#I'll use my own function for that, just easier to read

    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))   
    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 0.25, (width, height))#0.25 so one image is 4 seconds

    for image in images:        
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()
generate_video()
```

The above code however creating the video just with one image. There are 5 other images as well in the folder C:/New folder/Images/q/ but the video is generated only for the first one. Can someone please advise if anything is missing here ? Seems like the for loop is not working

Comment: Hard to tell without the images. Do they all have the same shape? (Note that the provided code cannot run, because of an indentation problem. But I take that is a copy&paste error).

Comment: Also 5 frames long videos are not very usual. Not all players handle that very well. I would test first with more images. Some 500. Loop on the images you have if needed. (Then, if it works, it will be time to try to make if work with only 5)

Comment: You could try adding print statements to the loop to ensure that it is both iterating, and that you have the data you are expecting inside the loop.

Comment: just use ffmpeg. it's the right tool for the job. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for converting pictures to video. OpenCV simply just uses ffmpeg for what you're asking of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a video you need your images to have the **same** resolution. If some images have different sizes `cv2.VideoWriter` quietly skips them without any errors.

So you may need to resize your images to fixed size:

```py
for image in images:
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image))
    image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
    video.write(image)
```

An example to reproduce this behavior:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

fc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
video = cv2.VideoWriter("1.mp4", fc, 0.25, (500, 500))

for idx in range(10):
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=3)
    if idx in [0, 2, 3]:  # only 3 frames will be in the final video
        image = np.full((500, 500, 3), fill_value=color, dtype=np.uint8)
    else:
        # slighly different size
        image = np.full((400, 500, 3), fill_value=color, dtype=np.uint8)

    video.write(image)
```